# js hook on html load process in browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, hook

Imagine I have following html with many items:

```
<html><body>
    <img src=http://host.com/pic1.jpg>
    <img src=http://host.com/pic1.jpg>
    <img src=http://host.com/pic1.jpg>
</html></body>
```

Site owner adds some script to the page **without other modifications**:

```
<script>
  var some_super_function = ... // what can i put here?
  some_super_function('host.com','ghost.com');
</script>
```

and during loading of this html, host.com is replaced with hgost.com, so images are loaded from another server, **as if** the urls were:

```
<html><body>
<img src=http://ghost.com/pic1.jpg>
<img src=http://ghost.com/pic1.jpg>
<img src=http://ghost.com/pic1.jpg>
</html></body>
```

I guess selecting `$('img')` and tuning `.attr()` is not a good idea, because this may work only after page has loaded and I don't want the browser to reference host.com at all.

I guess angularJS is doing something like that, isn't it?

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You can manipulate img elements only after they exist – and that means, the browser might have already started loading the URL in the src attribute. If you want to reliably prevent that – then don’t put that value into the `src` attribute to begin with. (Make it `data-src` or something like that – then your script can transfer that value into the `src` attribute.)

Comment: should be using `ng-src` in angular to avoid making invalid requests

Comment: You can use angular's http interceptor to programatically modify the route based on your defined criteria https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http (ctrl+f for `interceptor`)

Comment: I need to do it without angular, please read the question carefully.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko Can you modify the original html (e.g. replace `src="..."` with `data-src="..."`)?

Comment: @hege_hegedus yes, I can, but this is not a hook. I wish solution to be user friendly. I.E. no src editing. it should work with and without the script.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko: site owner add these some script, in body or head ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in firefox:

```
<body>
  <script>
    document.write('<!--');
    var body = null;
    setTimeout(function() {
      body = document.body.innerHTML
      console.log(body)
    }, 0)
  </script>
```

Now you can extract page contents from `body` variable, do with them whatever you wish and then put into page (with `jQuery('body').html(...)` for example).
I don't know if it would work if there were comments in the page. There are other ways to stop page from loading. Something like `document.write('<script>');`. I also tried `document.write('<style>');` in firefox, also works.

Comment: Looks like the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular ng-src and {{}} syntax to bind your img domain:

```js
var superFn = function(){ $('img').attr('src','ghost');  }
superFn();

angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl',myCtrl);

function myCtrl($scope){
 $scope.domain = "a3.mzstatic.com";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <img ng-src="http://{{domain}}/us/r30/Purple69/v4/d5/9e/6d/d59e6dfa-2176-7bc1-20a8-d3a1316c7bb8/icon100x100.png" > 
 <img ng-src="http://{{domain}}/us/r30/Purple69/v4/d5/9e/6d/d59e6dfa-2176-7bc1-20a8-d3a1316c7bb8/icon100x100.png" > 
 <img ng-src="http://{{domain}}/us/r30/Purple69/v4/d5/9e/6d/d59e6dfa-2176-7bc1-20a8-d3a1316c7bb8/icon100x100.png" >
 
 </div>
```

Comment: no, this is not what I want, I don't want to do any replacements in source html

Answer (score 1):

I guess I know what you need. You need to define a base, and manipulate it to serve your needs. Like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("<base href='http://yourimageurl.com/' />");
 </script>
```

You must use this code before body tag.

How can you set your image urls? This way you have to mirror file names in order to make it work. And only relative url's will work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use CSS to hide the images initially, wait until the document is ready, then change the images and display them in JS?

CSS

```
img {
    display: hide;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // ... selecting $('img') and tuning .attr() as mentioned in question

    // Show the images
    $('img').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I guess angularJS is doing something like that, isn't it?

No, angular use ng-src but for that you need to change the html

> Is this possible?

I don't think it's possible to do reliably, from the client side without changing the html. One issue is when the document is loading, the browser will fetch images as soon as browser hits the image src element, even if you can execute a script before that, since document is not loaded script does not have access to the element.

May be you could kick off a window.setInterval function to check for elements and change sources, still it's not going to be a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I not mistaken is it your requirement.

```js
var some_super_function = function(old_host,new_host)
 {
 $('img').each( function() {
        var newSrc;
  newSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace(old_host, new_host);  
  $(this).attr('src',newSrc);
  console.log($(this).attr('src'));
 }); 
 }

 some_super_function('host.com','ghost.com');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://host.com/pic1.jpg" alt="pic1"/><br/>
<img src="http://host.com/pic2.jpg" alt="pic2"/><br/>
<img src="http://host.com/pic3.jpg" alt="pic3"/><br/>
```

[**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/4vL79akr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In pure Js
you can do :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        some_super_function = function(orig, alt)
        {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("img[src*='"+orig+"']"), function(img)
            {
                var src = img.src;
                var host = src.replace(/^(.*\/\/[^\/?#]*).*$/,"$1");
                img.src = "http://"+src.replace(host, alt);
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="ol" src="http://www.intertools.net/lib/media/img/selector.png">
        <img id="io" src="http://www.intertools.net/lib/media/img/selector.png">
        <script>
            // callable anywhere
            some_super_function("www.intertools.net", "en.intertools.net");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

To avoid caching, you can even use (assuming you are using html5)

```
<html manifest="manifest.appcache">
```

Comment: images will start downloading from old address in this case

Comment: Not if you use manifest.appcache, i've tested, it works on chrome, but cannot test on others for now.
starting download is simply canceled by chrome himself.
behavior your wanna obtain is not possible because image are  loaded by each one during DOM loading... (and.. js = jquery = angular). I understand your issue, it is bad for traffic and bandwidth :/

Comment: you may look for httpd redirect or rewrite rule to annihilate the problem

Comment: On your browser network console, it will really start to download on last domain? or just reuse the cache ?

Comment: download starts immediately after img is parsed by browser